# How to handle rolling restarts through chef

Tags: chef-infra

How can a rolling restart of a cluster be handled through chef where change done on one of the node of cluster will lead to restarting/reconfiguration of other nodes in a cluster in a specific sequence.

Is it ideal to initiate remote shh connections from inside a recipe running on one node to other nodes of a cluster to do such reconfiguration?

Comment: @StephenKing has it right.  You need to write your cookbooks in such a way that each node will know what to do each time it runs.  If every node runs once every 5 minutes, you should see full convergence pretty quickly.  If that's not good enough, then use a tool like consul or confd to control this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the chef clients check in at different times (in a repeating interval). Therefore, usually the apply the changes at different times.

There is no coordination built in that would trigger the chef-client runs (e.g. triggered by a push job) in a coordinated way.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by using some state. [chef-dominodes](https://github.com/websterclay/chef-dominodes) does so with help of databags

```
dominodes 'rolling_apache_restarts'
  recipe do
    execute 'service apache2 restart'
  end

  action :nothing
end
```